# How to access ios core audio(AudioQueue) on Nativescript

Tags: ios, audio, plugins, nativescript

I'm new to nativescript and developing ios version app now.
I have some trouble handling Audio Queue callback.

I need capturing raw audio buffer data via device microphone.(evaluating input level in millisecond order)1
To do this, I'm trying to call ios native AudioToolBox/AudioQueueNewInput API from my custom plugin.

Finally, it run with no error, but the callback "inCallbackProc" is never fired...

Here is my code.

myplugin.ios.js

```
var kSamplingRate = 44100;
var inUserData = null;
var inCallbackRunLoopMode = kCFRunLoopDefaultMode;
var inFlags = 0;
//var outAQ = AudioQueueRef.alloc().init(); // error
//var outAQ = new OpaqueAudioQueue(); //error
var outAQ;
var inFormat = 
    new AudioStreamBasicDescription(
    kSamplingRate,
    kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat,
    4,
    1,
    4,
    1,
    8,
    0
);

var buffers = [null, null, null];

var audiomodule = {
    inCallbackProc : function(
        inUserData, 
        inAQ, 
        inBuffer, 
        inStartTime, 
        inNumberPacketDescriptions, 
        inPacketDescs 
        ){
            console.log("callbacked");
        }
    ,record: function(){
        console.log("recordstarting");

        AudioQueueNewInput (
         inFormat, 
         this.inCallbackProc.copy,
         inUserData, 
         CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
         inCallbackRunLoopMode, 
         inFlags, 
         outAQ
         );
        for (i in [0, 1, 2]) {
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(outAQ, 256, buffers[i])
            AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(outAQ, buffers[i], 0, null)
           }

    AudioQueueStart(outAQ, null);
    }

};

module.exports = audiomodule;
```

app.js

```
var MyPlugin = require("myplugin");

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    if (page.ios) {
        MyPlugin.record();
    }
};
```

When Executing this code, I can find "recordstarting" in console log with no error, but can't find "callbacked".

I have read this doc.
[NativeScript Doc - Marshaling](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/marshalling/Marshalling-Overview.html)

I appreciate anyone help or comment.

Comment: I found that similar audio plugin exists for NativeScript and you could use it for playing and recording an audio  - https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio

Comment: Hi Nikolay, that plugin is based on AVAudioRecorder. And that API might not be suitable for my app, because of latency. pls see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7402810/6606449). I need capturing raw audio.

Comment: I was unable to find suitable plugin for your project, which is capturing raw audio. However you could use the described steps here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039291/simplest-way-to-capture-raw-audio-from-audio-input-for-real-time-processing-on-a and to create your own plugin, which is providing this functionality. Another option is to log a new issue in the bradmartin's plugin repo for raw audio support.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I decided to create my own plugin and described my experience as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create my own plugin.
My own Objective-c library wraps native AudioRecord(Core Audio) API.
And own plugin js exposes the library functions.
Finally, it works, callback work also.

mylibrary(Objective-c)

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(NSString *result);
```

myplugin.ios.js

```
mylibrary.completionHandler = (
function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```